# Is it possible to make hidden files or folders show up on the desktop?

Tags: unity, gnome, hidden-files

Is there any way to make hidden (.name) files and folders visible from the desktop?

Comment: I mean that the hidden file is in the home/Desktop folder, if somebody misunderstand the question.

Comment: If you want to see hidden files/folders IN NAUTILUS, just hit control-h

Comment: I don't think it is possible unless you unhide them first, but mostly the hidden files are configuration files, and renaming them (removing the .dot) make them not work!!  The programs are looking for .program files!

Comment: I have a 17.04 and put some .named files in desktop folder, they are hidden to Nautilus, but are visible from desktop.